# For what $n = 1, 2, 3, . . . $ is it true that if $A \in O(n)$, $\det(A) = −1$, then $A$ is a reflection.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Clearly it's not true for $n=1$.

But for $n=2$, I am not sure, suspect it to be true.

I can say that it is not true for $n\ge 3$. Because $A =
  \begin{bmatrix}
    -1 & 0 &0\\
    0 & -1&0\\
0 & 0&-1
  \end{bmatrix}$ is not a reflection, and any $n\ge 4$ will contain this structure.

How to show that for $n=2$ this statement is true?

Comment: If you say that "clearly" it's not true for $n=1$ you may want to specify what a reflection is

Answer (score 1):

If reflection means a one-dimensional eigenspace of eigenvector $-1$ and a one-codimensional eigenspace of eigenvector $+1$ then the criterion $\det A=-1$ works exqactly for dimension $\le 2$, the reason being that for $n\ge 3$ (as you found out) one can have a three-dimensional eigenspace of eigenvalue $-1$.

To see that for $n=2$ we really do have the desired eigenspaces,  note that the characteristic polynomial $X^2-\operatorname{tr(A)}X-1$ has two real roots of distinct signs, so we must have *some* positive and *some* negative eigenvector. From orthogonality, the eigenvalue must have modulus $1$, hence the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

The result is true for $n=2$.

In dimension $2$, an element $u \in O(2)$ is either a rotation or a reflection.

The determinant of a rotation is equal to one. So if $\det u=-1$, $u$ is a reflection.

Comment: yes, can you prove an element in $O(2)$ is either rotation or reflection? or explain how we know such

Comment: The determinant of $u \in O(2)$ Is either $+1$ or $-1$. If it is $-1$ you'll prove that $u$ has $-1$ is an Eigen value and that $u$ is a reflection. If it is $+1$, take an orthonormal basis $(i,j)$. The image of $i$ is $a i+b j$ with $a^2+b^2=1$. The one of $j=-b i+a j$ which proves that $u$ is a rotation in that case.